# Measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, function

Can I measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?

**I.e.:**

```
compare('Test', 'est') # Returns 1
compare('Test', 'Tes') # Returns 1
compare('Test', 'Tast') # Returns 1
compare('Test', 'Taste') # Returns 2
compare('Test', 'tazT') # Returns 5
```

Comment: Do you mean difference?

Comment: Search for "levenshtein distance ruby" and see [Levenshtein-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). (I'm not quite sure why the last call should return 5 though; the maximum edit distance is [limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Upper_and_lower_bounds) by the input lengths.)

Comment: @nzifnab So so, I need an integer return.

Comment: Check "[What is an efficient way to measure similarity between two strings? (Levenshtein Distance makes stack too deep)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8619785/128421)".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found this for you:

```
def levenshtein_distance(s, t)
  m = s.length
  n = t.length
  return m if n == 0
  return n if m == 0
  d = Array.new(m+1) {Array.new(n+1)}

  (0..m).each {|i| d[i][0] = i}
  (0..n).each {|j| d[0][j] = j}
  (1..n).each do |j|
    (1..m).each do |i|
      d[i][j] = if s[i-1] == t[j-1]  # adjust index into string
                  d[i-1][j-1]       # no operation required
                else
                  [ d[i-1][j]+1,    # deletion
                    d[i][j-1]+1,    # insertion
                    d[i-1][j-1]+1,  # substitution
                  ].min
                end
    end
  end
  d[m][n]
end

[ ['fire','water'], ['amazing','horse'], ["bamerindos", "giromba"] ].each do |s,t|
  puts "levenshtein_distance('#{s}', '#{t}') = #{levenshtein_distance(s, t)}"
end
```

That's awesome output: =)

```
levenshtein_distance('fire', 'water') = 4
levenshtein_distance('amazing', 'horse') = 7
levenshtein_distance('bamerindos', 'giromba') = 9
```

Source: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Ruby

Answer (score 32):

Much easier and fast due to native C binding:

```
gem install levenshtein-ffi
gem install levenshtein

require 'levenshtein'

Levenshtein.normalized_distance string1, string2, threshold
```

http://rubygems.org/gems/levenshtein
http://rubydoc.info/gems/levenshtein/0.2.2/frames

Comment: note that this does not handle Unicode (the levensthein-ffi gem as of this writing)

Answer (score 27):

There is an utility method in Rubygems that actually should be public but it's not, anyway:

```
require "rubygems/text"
ld = Class.new.extend(Gem::Text).method(:levenshtein_distance)

p ld.call("asd", "sdf") => 2
```

Comment: You could say it is already public if you include the module. In your code do `include Gem::Text` and then use it like so: `levenshtein_distance('asd', 'sdf')`

Comment: The document of `Gem::Text` is here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Text.html  The `include` way stated by @JeromeDalbert is most convenient for most uses, whereas @Nakilon's answer is most complete in the sense it avoids any possibility of namespace conflict.

Answer (score 23):

Ruby 2.3 and later ship with the [`did_you_mean` gem](https://github.com/ruby/did_you_mean) which includes [`DidYouMean::Levenshtein.distance`](https://github.com/ruby/did_you_mean/blob/fbe5aaaae8405d19dc1bf691c5bead6348c6da10/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb). Fit for most cases and available by default.

```rb
DidYouMean::Levenshtein.distance("Test", "est") # => 1
```

Answer (score 17):

Much simpler, I'm a Ruby show-off at times...

```
# Levenshtein distance, translated from wikipedia pseudocode by ross

def lev s, t
  return t.size if s.empty?
  return s.size if t.empty?
  return [ (lev s.chop, t) + 1,
           (lev s, t.chop) + 1,
           (lev s.chop, t.chop) + (s[-1, 1] == t[-1, 1] ? 0 : 1)
       ].min
end
```

Comment: This may be slow, but it's a great starting point if you want to adapt the code to calculate the Levenshtein distance for something other than strings (say, lists of words).

Comment: The `require 'levenshtein'` answer also works for arrays of words, in fact arrays of anything that understands `:hash` and `:eql?`.

Comment: This answer smells the most ruby-ish.  Recursion and chop FTW!

Comment: This is a cool little demo but **not** suitable for production. Try `lev "123456789123456789", "123456789"`...

Comment: I used this to compare two strings, one 17 characters and one 21. It ran for 5 minutes before I cancelled it. The accepted answer returned instantly.

Answer (score 5):

I made a [damerau-levenshtein gem](https://github.com/GlobalNamesArchitecture/damerau-levenshtein) where algorithms are implemented in C

```
require "damerau-levenshtein"
dl = DamerauLevenshtein
dl.distance("Something", "Smoething") #returns 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I like DigitalRoss' solution above. However, as pointed out by dawg, its runtime grows on the order `O(3^n)`, which is no good for longer strings. 
That solution can be sped up significantly using memoization, or 'dynamic programming':

```
def lev(string1, string2, memo={})
  return memo[[string1, string2]] if memo[[string1, string2]]
  return string2.size if string1.empty?
  return string1.size if string2.empty?
  min = [ lev(string1.chop, string2, memo) + 1,
          lev(string1, string2.chop, memo) + 1,
          lev(string1.chop, string2.chop, memo) + (string1[-1] == string2[-1] ? 0 : 1)
       ].min
  memo[[string1, string2]] = min
  min
end
```

We then have much better runtime, (I think it's almost linear? I'm not really sure).

```
[9] pry(main)> require 'benchmark'
=> true
[10] pry(main)> @memo = {}
=> {}
[11] pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime{puts lev("Hello darkness my old friend", "I've come to talk with you again")}
26
=> 0.007071999832987785
```