# Compare text of many strings

Tags: php, sql, ruby, algorithm

Let's assume we have many rows in db that needs to be searched for duplicates.

Duplicates are considered having of more than 95% text match.

Number of items can be more than 50000 and more, and items is not just 1 word it can have up to 5000 characters.

What will be a strategy to find this kind of duplicate texts?

I don't think it's effective to choose rows one by one and compare it to other 49999 rows, this is just plain nonsense.

Any other possible solutions?

Comment: What have you tried? Look at "[Measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323571/measure-the-distance-between-two-strings-with-ruby)"

Comment: levenshtein(), or similar_text()

Comment: i don't see effective strategy for this kind of task, because i need to compare any single item with every other item which is not effective.

Comment: question is not about similar_text(), in how much time you will compare 50000 one by one having 5000 chars with this? hour?

Comment: @Dagon be aware that using those functions is VERY CPU expensive. If you have these values in a database, you should put a FULLTEXT index on them, and use MATCH AGAINST. It would be a bit faster, use the database for what it is for, but sadly is still row by row

Comment: they where just ideas, I would settle on no approach until i had tested and benchmarked, something the OP seems unable to do.

Comment: i benchmarked in my head, this type of approach is not effective and slow and can't be ever considered as solution.

Comment: i sleep with super models in my head, you have a boring imagination

Comment: This is an interesting, though somewhat vague, question.  You may get more useful answers by editing your question to include an "ideal" method `match?(s1, s2)` that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether strings `s1` and `s2` "match".  (I don't mean `def match?(s1, s2) s1==s2 end` :-) ) You might want to look at the [Plagarism Detection Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection#Approaches), in part for references and links.

Comment: search of Google `text comparison algorithm fingerprinting` gets this: http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf probably a good place to start if you are thinking of designing your own algorithm.

Comment: Not sure why this has gotten 4 up-votes already when it doesn't show the beginnings of research via Google or even a search of StackOverflow of the subject.

Comment: @Beartech: slow news day.

Comment: True, I got sucked in too.

Comment: You need to define your notion of "95% text match".

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is define what "95% text match" means. For example, consider the following:

```
The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.
The qZick rZd fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.
```

Those two sentences are each 49 characters long. They differ only in the two "Z" characters. So 47 characters are identical, meaning that the texts are 95.92% similar. If you go by character.

If you go by word, then the texts are only 80% similar.

Does order matter. Let's say you have a text that's 4,800 characters in length. We'll call that text `fixed`. Now you're asked to compare that against something that is two words prepended. That is:

```
some stuff <fixed>
```

By many measures, that is more than 95% similar to `fixed`. Or how about:

```
<fixed> some stuff
```

Is that more similar to `fixed` than the previous? What about a text that has `fixed` in reverse? What about a text that contains all of `fixed`, but there are a few extra words. Missing words?

I'm not asking these questions to be pedantic. How you define similarity makes a big difference in how you go about solving your problem.

You're right, by the way, that comparing every text against all the others is not the way to go. You end up doing `(n^2 - n)/2` document comparisons. When `n == 50,000`, that's on the order of 1.25 *billion*.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible approaches (please treat it more like a scheme than a solution):

- Preprocess each item by counting occurrences of words `{"be": 12, "cow": 3, "show": 4, ...}`.
- Define a measure between those dictionaries.
- Compare pairs.

The last step may not necesserly be `O(n^2)` since the similarity measure is transitive. It depends on how many similar texts you have.

After finding classes of similarity you can investigate them further for checking the 95% condition in detail.

Comment: Good idea. What if you counted just the occurrence of the first letter of each word i.e. `{a: 55, b: 32, c: 5... `, or even first letter and word length? You could probably come up with some sort of fingerprinting system similar to the one used by sites like Shazam. Rows that are not even close to each other in number of words with matching first letters would be filtered out quickly. You could then index in all sorts of ways on each row. I think most of the work would be in designing many columns that store some sort of fingerprint value that weeds out at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

what are the real requirements? identify uniques with near 100% confidence? identify possible duplicates with high confidence? mark low confidence decisions for human review? provide matching probability?

probably this will not be a one pass solution but an iterative process where you have to store the progress. you could start with a square matrix of 50,000 rows (yes thats big) to store matching probability min/max values initialized with 0%/100%. you should chose an efficient criteria how to sort rows and how to iterate through the matrix to avoid memory swapping. then you cold start to refine the matching probability interval with cheap algorithms. e.g. you could use text length to reduce the maximum matching probability to 0% if size differs by 5% (or any value that does not provide false negatives). on the remaining combinations you can run more expensive comparisons. e.g. for exact string matches you can set the minimum probability to 100%. if the number of words differs you could lower the probability. with every iteration you increase the number of already decided combinations. you can verify your algorithms in every step. text size, word count, exact text are keys you could build an index making comparisons cheap. also you could remove rows proven to be unique against all others in every step.

i'm not sure if i interpreted your problems correctly but finding a golden algorithm for a 95% criteria may be not sufficient as there is no other way than comparing one against each other. you have at least 3 problems, an efficient process, good decision criteria and an efficient implementation.