# How to get the maximum-character-matching string from an array of strings

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array of strings, which is a list of correct standard-disease names. I have another array of strings that is also a list of diseases with some variation in spelling; sometimes they are misspelled in the second array.

I want to map each disease name in the second array to the first array. This is not 100% possible, but I want to suggest a correct mapping against each incorrect disease name. Does someone know an algorithm?

Comment: If you are looking for an algorithm, then it has nothing to do with Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

It is the minimum number of character changes required to transform one word to another.

More discussions and implementation can be found at "[Measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323571/measure-the-distance-between-two-strings-with-ruby)".

Comment: The gem you linked was last updated two years ago, and is copyrighted in 2009. It describes that it cannot handle unicode.

Comment: Yes. thank you. A gem is not really needed for this. Many Ruby implementations are available.