# Is it possible to bring the variable value even if is there some mismatch in variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
variable_123_abc = 20
```

If I search with variable_345_abc it should bring the value 20 is it possible in ruby?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean if the variable is of form `variable_???_abc` for any `???`?

Comment: yes, variable_???_abc it should bring the value of 20

Comment: what is the question again?

Comment: If I assigned a value to the variable variable_123_abc = 20, If I search with variable_<any number>_abc it should written 20 is it possible?

Comment: What does "search with" mean?

Comment: @sakthivel well I think I know what you mean but I don't know the solution. Try editing your question to make it clearer then it may get re-opened. Perhaps provide some context i.e. what is this for and why are you doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I tried this.

```
variable_123_abc = 20

value = begin
 variable_456_abc
rescue NameError => e
  var = e.message.scan(/`(.+)'/).flatten.first
  closest_var = binding.local_variables.find {|i| levenshtein_distance(i,var) <= 3 }
  binding.local_variable_get(closest_var) if closest_var
end

p value
#=> 20
```

---

It makes use of [an answer from thread - Measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323861/794242)

```
def levenshtein_distance(s, t)
  m = s.length
  n = t.length
  return m if n == 0
  return n if m == 0
  d = Array.new(m+1) {Array.new(n+1)}

  (0..m).each {|i| d[i][0] = i}
  (0..n).each {|j| d[0][j] = j}
  (1..n).each do |j|
    (1..m).each do |i|
      d[i][j] = if s[i-1] == t[j-1]  # adjust index into string
                  d[i-1][j-1]       # no operation required
                else
                  [ d[i-1][j]+1,    # deletion
                    d[i][j-1]+1,    # insertion
                    d[i-1][j-1]+1,  # substitution
                  ].min
                end
    end
  end
  d[m][n]
end
```

Comment: With the `did_you_mean` gem that ships with Ruby 2.3, you could use `closest_var = e.corrections.first`

Comment: @Stefan Aha...great tip!  Will have to give it a try someday - currently on Windows, no 2.3 yet for it :-|