# How to compare two strings and find the percent of similarity?

Tags: ruby, string, percentage, string-comparison

How to **compare two strings** and print the *percentage of similarity*. It is easy to find similarities between string but *displaying it in percentage is hard.*
How to achieve it in **Ruby** ?

Comment: This is a really low effort question. **What have you tried?** Give examples. Show some code.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Levenshtein Distance, then compare that result as a percentage of characters in the source string.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you looking for an algorithm or method for comparing strings measured as a percentage? Or are you looking for help writing a specific algorithm (that you haven't mentioned) in Ruby? *It is easy to find similarities between string*... ok, how is "similarity" specifically defined that case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure the distance between two strings with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323571/measure-the-distance-between-two-strings-with-ruby)

Comment: @tadman I don't have any idea how to do this :/

Comment: That's okay, that's why you experiment and try things. Being lost isn't something you should be ashamed of, but questions of this sort are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to go out from the Levenshtein distance, which will tell you how many operations needed to convert a string to another.

In Ruby, there is a gem you can use for this, called `Levenshtein`.

To convert the number of operations needed to a percentage, you can go out from 100% is having to write the string all the way from the beginning and have no similarities. That would be the length of the longest string. Another option would be to use the average length of the strings, but in this example, I will use the longest.

Here is a method using the [`levenshtein` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/levenshtein/versions/0.2.2) and getting a percentage of how close they are:

```
require 'levenshtein'
def distance_percent(first,second)
    max_distance = [first,second].max_by(&:length).length
    distance = Levenshtein.distance(first,second)
    (100.0 / max_distance * distance).round.to_s + "%"
end
```

Here are some examples of what that method would return for different strings.

```
string_one = "1234567890"
string_two = "1234567890"
puts distance_percent(string_one, string_two)

# => 0%
```

This returns `0%` since the distance between them is 0.

```
string_one = "1234512345"
string_two = "6789067890"
puts distance_percent(string_one, string_two)

# => 100%
```

This will return `100%` since there are none of the same characters.

```
string_one = "This is a string"
string_two = "This is another string"
puts distance_percent(string_one, string_two)

# => 27%
```

This will return `27%` since 27 percent of the string is different from each other.