# Is there a way to compare how similar a sequence of numbers is to another sequence of numbers in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, math, numbers, compare

I'm trying to compare how similar 2 sequences are to eachother in Ruby. For example, 1234657890 to 1234567890 is 80% similar. I've thought about decreasing the number by 1 digit and then checking but then it makes that example 40% similar

Comment: Why are the two strings from your first example 90% similar?

Comment: Because only 1 character differs. Ehh, maybe you could say it's 80% but it was just an example

Comment: Okay, then please edit your example with the correct information.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "similar". There are many different possible answers. E.g. are `abe` and `ace` equally similar as `abe` and `abce`?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323571/measure-the-distance-between-two-strings-with-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
num_str1 = '1234567890'
num_str2 = '1234657890'

num_str1.chars.zip(num_str2.chars).count { |a, b| a == b }
  #=> 8
```

This converts each string to character-arrays, then pairing elements by index, before comparing them. The percentage calculation is left as an exercise. See [ruby-docs.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core) for more info on the methods used.